# Prove a language is NP-Complete

Tags: computer-science, computational-complexity, computability

$A$ is NP-complete.

$B$ is P.

$A \cap B = \emptyset $

$A \cup B \neq \sum^{*}$

Prove that $A \cup B $ is NP-complete.

How can I prove this ? I think if anything can be P-reducible to A then it can also be reducible to $A \cup B$, but don't know how to formally say this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** Just use the usual argument. Take a procedure that decides if something is in $A \cup B$ and turn this, with a polynomial-time transformation, into a procedure that decides if something is in $A$. For this you need to use another procedure that decides, in polynomial-time, if something is in $B$.

**Concretely** Let's say you have a procedure $P_{AB}$ that decides if something is in $A \cup B$, that is $P_{AB}(\omega) = \text{true}$ if $\omega \in A \cup B$ and $P_{AB}(\omega) = \text{false}$ if $\omega \not\in A \cup B$. Similarly, let's say $P_B$ is a polynomial-time procedure that decides if something is in $B$, that is $P_B(\omega) = \text{true}$ if $\omega \in B$ and $P_B(\omega) = \text{false}$ if $\omega \not\in B$.

Now we have to build a procedure $P_A(\omega)$ that decides if something is in $A$. Ofcourse, first it will call $P_{AB}(\omega)$ and $P_B(\omega)$. Now, when is $\omega \in A$ and when is $\omega \not\in A$. Recall at this point that $A \cap B = \emptyset$.

Comment: Can I just say, because there's f that reduces any NP language C to A, we create a function f2, f2 = f(x) or (x in B)?  But I don't know how do I use the condition that $A \cup B$ is not the whole language.

Comment: You could build that $f_2$, but then you'd have to argue that in that way every NP language $C$ is reduced to $A \cup B$. If you follow my hint, that part of the argument is hidden in the theorem that that says if you reduce a language $X$ to an NP language $Y$, then $X$ is NP as well.

Comment: The assumption that $A \cup B$ is not the whole language is not needed. Note that if $B$ in in $P$, the so is the complement of $B$. (and $A \cup B = \Sigma^*$ in your case would imply P = NP).

Comment: How about $A \cap B = \emptyset$?

Comment: That's needed. And I just noticed that your $f$ and $f_2$ are not doing the right thing: they should be functions from $\Sigma^*$ to itself, mapping elements of $C$ to $A$ (resp. $A \cup B$).

Comment: I think the theorem should be if $A$ is reduced to $A \cup B$ then $A \cup B$ is NP-complete?

Comment: In fact, I find it difficult to reduce $A$ to $A \cup B$

Comment: I've added a more concrete description of the reduction to the answer.